# how I can get object in var with php

Tags: php, wordpress

I use this wordpress function

```
$all_meta_for_user = get_user_meta( $user->ID );
$city = $all_meta_for_user['dokan_profile_settings'][0];
print_r( $city );
```

this what I get

> a:11:{s:10:"store_name";s:14:"test_trioszhrt";s:6:"social";a:0:{}s:7:"payment";a:0:{}s:5:"phone";s:8:"12541025";s:10:"show_email";s:2:"no";s:7:"address";a:6:{s:8:"street_1";s:8:"kkloadaa";s:8:"street_2";s:0:"";s:4:"city";s:7:"tunisia";s:3:"zip";s:1:"1";s:7:"country";s:2:"NP";s:5:"state";s:3:"GAN";}s:8:"location";s:0:"";s:6:"banner";i:0;s:12:"find_address";s:0:"";s:14:"dokan_category";s:0:"";s:9:"store_ppp";i:10;}

I want to get only city?
how I can do this?

Comment: Why did you delete your other question just to post it again? I told you what function to use on your other question.

Comment: Thought I had seen this one before! @PatrickQ

Comment: the first question is incomprehensible

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a `serialize`d string. `unserialize` it to a php value (in this case it is **array**) and use:

```
$s = 'a:11:{s:10:"store_name";s:14:"test_trioszhrt";s:6:"social";a:0:{}s:7:"payment";a:0:{}s:5:"phone";s:8:"12541025";s:10:"show_email";s:2:"no";s:7:"address";a:6:{s:8:"street_1";s:8:"kkloadaa";s:8:"street_2";s:0:"";s:4:"city";s:7:"tunisia";s:3:"zip";s:1:"1";s:7:"country";s:2:"NP";s:5:"state";s:3:"GAN";}s:8:"location";s:0:"";s:6:"banner";i:0;s:12:"find_address";s:0:"";s:14:"dokan_category";s:0:"";s:9:"store_ppp";i:10;}';
$data = unserialize($s);
print_r($data);
echo $data['address']['city'];
```

[Fiddle](https://3v4l.org/KYh0g).

Comment: thannnnnk you :D